# PHP Session Stop working

Tags: php, session

I don't know why my session suddenly stops.
Here is my code.

File 1:

```
<?php session_start();
$_SESSION['user_session'] = 'test';
?>
```

File 2:

```
<?php
session_start();
echo '<pre>' . print_r($_SESSION, TRUE) . '</pre>';

?>
```

I use PHP 7, I already tried other remedies but cant use my session.

Comment: One `session_start()` is enough

Comment: And try `$_SESSION['user_session']` instead of `$_SESSION`

Comment: @Swellar I thinks they are supposed to mean two seperate files.

Comment: don't use two times `session_start();` Or these codes belong to two separate files?

Comment: @Ivar Who knows, OP didn't mentioned it

Comment: [simple as looking for php session start](http://php.net/manual/es/function.session-start.php)

Comment: Yes I mean two separate files sorry for miscommunication

Comment: I ried two simple pages to debug

Comment: Have you tried echoing `$_SESSION['user_session']`?

Comment: Yes and it is still not working, it jsut suddenly happen, I already made some functions, then im in shock that even my functions that is already working is already broken

Comment: Ok how about using error_reporting(-1); above the code and see what kind of errors you have there.

Comment: I restarted my machine then suddenly all my modules is working and my session is up again, I dont exactly know what happen but I think it is connected to Windows update.

Answer (score 0):

You have first create session for user session

You can use to it

```
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['user_session'];
```